# angular- how to hide one element and show another with ng-blur?

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide this div:

```
<div class="desc" ng-show="desc">
```

and show this div

```
<div  class="lists"ng-show="lists" 
       ng-repeat="x in todoWork | orderBy:['todoPriority', 'todoTime']" 
       ng-class="{strike:x.done}">
```

on ng-blur directive.

I tried this but,

```
$scope.myFunc1 = function() {  
 if($scope.myForm1.description.$dirty && $scope.myForm1.datetime.$dirty && $scope.myForm1.priority.$dirty==true){
    $scope.lists =true;
    $scope.desc=false;

 }
};
```

but only first one is executing.Even if try to write another function for second one the problem remains.

Comment: Please, clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide first one and show second one then why are not you using a single variable like the below:

First one `<div ng-show="desc">`

Second one `<div ng-show="!desc">`